# VB.NET Cannot Convert ISingleResult to String

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq, datacontext

I am having problems storing the result of my stored procedure inside of one of my datacontext. I have created a String variable called "A_Choice" that is to be used in saving the result of the stored procedure; however, my sp returns a value as System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult(Of IT_Web_Ticket_System.GetCategoryA_IDResult). How can I convert this result to string or even store this value at all. Here the offending code:

```
Using database As New ITTaskDatabaseDataContext
            A_Choice = database.GetCategoryA_ID(CategoryAComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString())
End Using
```

Also, here is some WORKING code where I use the same DataContext that does not return a value:

```
Using database As New ITTaskDatabaseDataContext
            CategoryBComboBox.ItemsSource = database.GetCategoryB()
            CategoryBComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"
            CategoryBComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "ID"
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you want to use the ReturnValue of the procedure. From the docs on ISingleResult https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534556%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
 A_Choice = database.GetCategoryA_ID(CategoryAComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()).ReturnValue.ToString()
```

Comment: This is a step closer I think; however, my stored procedure is (as it is supposed to) is returning an Integer value (0). How can I return a string?

Comment: @Devin, I don't think DBMS(What are you using?) stored procedures can return values other than INT, maybe you wanted a function? Or does your SP "return" stuff from a select statement? You should prolly update the question with the relvant details

Comment: You are correct and yes it does return data from a select statement. How do I capture this data?